# Use axel to get source instead curl for fetchurl in NixOS

Tags: curl, nixos, nix, axel

I'm trying to start a shell with Cuda. I have following shell.nix file

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> { } }:

pkgs.mkShell {
  name = "cuda-env-shell";
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [
    unzip
    # other packages
    cudatoolkit
    # other packages
    binutils
  ];
}
```

But this fails due to following error. I have faced this before with large files like davinci-resolve for example. For davinci-resolve, my solution was to create a new flake using axel with 10 connections and it worked nicely every single time. Right now I'm facing this issue with Cuda.

```
[1/0/3 built, 4 copied (183.8/183.8 MiB), 42.8 MiB DL] building cuda_11.8.0_520.61.05_linux.run:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left
error: builder for '/nix/store/idz14mzbsv4k5v5ims095jcjk2r50glr-cuda_11.8.0_520.61.05_linux.run.drv' failed with exit code 1;
       last 7 log lines:
       >
       > trying https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.8.0/local_installers/cuda_11.8.0_520.61.05_linux.run
       >   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
       >                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
       >  49 4135M   49 2044M    0     0   772k      0  1:31:20  0:45:08  0:46:12     0
       > curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I want to get Cuda but can I retrieve the src using axel instead of curl? I tried something like following but it doesn't seem to be valid syntax?

```
    cudatoolkit.overrideAttrs
    (finalAttrs: previousAttrs: {
      pname = previousAttrs.pname + "-bar";
      src = runCommandLocal "${previousAttrs.pname}.run" rec { } ''
        axel \
          --num-connections=10 \
          --verbose \
          --insecure \
          --output $out \
          "https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.8.0/local_installers/cuda_11.8.0_520.61.05_linux.run"
      '';
    })
```

Error:

```
        at /nix/store/0g53xyh39z3y90p4d8r341wbqyjy1zhl-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:395:7:

          394|       depsHostHost                = elemAt (elemAt dependencies 1) 0;
          395|       buildInputs                 = elemAt (elemAt dependencies 1) 1;
             |       ^
          396|       depsTargetTarget            = elemAt (elemAt dependencies 2) 0;

       error: Dependency is not of a valid type: element 13 of buildInputs for cuda-env-shell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first step, it is necessary to add parentheses around the expression `(cudatoolkit.overrideAttrs (finalAttrs: previousAttrs: { .. }))` to avoid breaking the list.

In the second step, it is necessary to add an [`outputHash`](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/advanced-attributes#adv-attr-outputHash) to enable the builder to accept the downloaded source. Initially, you can use

```
src = runCommandLocal "${previousAttrs.pname}.run" {
  outputHashMode = "flat";
  outputHashAlgo = "sha256";
  outputHash = "";
}
```

to trigger an error that displays the hash of the source.
In this case, I obtained the hash: `sha256-kiPErzrr5Ke77Zq9mxY7A6GzS4VfvCtKDRtwasCaWhY=`.

Finally, it is necessary to add `axel` to the environment executing the command. Since it is only used for downloading the source, you can add it to the`nativeBuildInputs` of `runCommandLocal`. Additionally, you can replace `axel` in the script with `${pkgs.axel}/bin/axel`.

```
{pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}}:
pkgs.mkShell {
  name = "cuda-env-shell";
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [

    (cudatoolkit.overrideAttrs (finalAttrs: previousAttrs: {
      pname = previousAttrs.pname;
      src =
        runCommandLocal "${previousAttrs.pname}.run" {
          nativeBuildsInputs = [axel];
          # outputHashMode = "flat";
          # outputHashAlgo = "sha256";
          # outputHash = "";
          outputHash = "sha256-kiPErzrr5Ke77Zq9mxY7A6GzS4VfvCtKDRtwasCaWhY=";
        } ''
          # ${pkgs.axel}/bin/axel \
          axel \
            --num-connections=10 \
            --verbose \
            --insecure \
            --output "$out" \
            "https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.8.0/local_installers/cuda_11.8.0_520.61.05_linux.run"
        '';
    }))
  ];
}
```